# Node JS Setup Message when uncaughtException happens

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a question about Gracefully Shutdown on Node JS

I have setup method that will sent an automatic mail to developer if something happen on server that causing server stop working (either wrong code or etc).

these are highlight of my code

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.error((new Date).toUTCString() + ' uncaughtException:', err.message);
    console.error(err.stack);
    //Mandrill
         ...
    });
});
```

What I got in Email is only these

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined`

but what I want is I want to include the logs on the mail like this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined
at ...\routes\v3\users.js:57:20
    at ...\node_modules\mongoose-deep-populate\lib\plugin.js:81:11
    at nextLevel (...\node_modules\mongoose-deep-populate\lib\plugin.js:237:36)
    at Promise.one (...\node_modules\mongoose-deep-populate\lib\plugin.js:232:27)
    at Promise.<anonymous> (...\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:177:8)
    at Promise.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at Promise.emit (...\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:84:38)
    at Promise.fulfill (...\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mpromise\lib\promise.js:97:20)
    at Promise.resolve (...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\promise.js:114:23)
    at ...\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:2051:23
```

any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also mailing error to myself in case of errors. My code is

```
module.exports = function(error, req, res, next){
  if(error){
    var body = '<h3>Error stack </h3>'+ error.stack;
    sendMail(['me@myself.com'],'Ha Ha 500',body.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />')) // replece function for formatting, sendMail() sends mail through amazon ses 
   }
  }
```

here is the sreen shot of mail
[image]